# How to discard global selector rule inside certain tag?

Tags: css, emotion

I have global css rule:

```css
li *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Inside `<nav>` tag I need to make this role do not work. For example I have the code:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class='foo'>Foo</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
.foo {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

I want the role for class `foo` to work. I tried:

```css
nav li *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: unset;
}
```

It does not work. To declare rule for class `foo` with another selector together is not an option for my case:

```css
.foo, nav li .foo:last-child {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

It is because I am defining rules in js framework emotion.

I know I can add `!important` to `.foo` rule but it is not a good practice. What can I do to resolve my question?

UPD. I found that in emotion I can use `&` placeholder for the name of the class. And I can define the property of `margin`:

```css
 &, nav li &:last-child {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a global selector *not* target an individual element - you'll have to overwrite the global rule with a secondary rule which applies the behaviour that you want to only apply to the specific element. Note that this secondary rule should have higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

The simplest way to do this would be with the selector `li .foo`, which has more specificity than the `li *:last-child` selector, and thus overwrites it:

[image: Foo]

This can be seen in the following:

```css
li *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li .foo {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class='foo'>Foo</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```